# Office 2010 buttons orange gradient

Tags: wpf, silverlight, graphics, user-interface, colors

Someone knows which colors and offsets are used in Microsoft Office 2010 buttons (orange color).
It would be best, if You send me as answer ready XAML code for brush background of buttons.
Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use my [gradient generator](https://github.com/gerich-home/xaml-gradient-generator)
It takes some image and generates code for linear gradient brush. So you can use print screen button on your keyboard, than open this image in gradient generator and you will get something like that:
[image: example]

So, here is gradient code:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="orange-button_center" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#fff1ca58" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0153846153846154" Color="#fffdf9e8" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0307692307692307" Color="#fffdeeb3" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0461538461538461" Color="#fffdeca9" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.076923076923077" Color="#fffde99b" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.107692307692308" Color="#fffde690" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.123076923076923" Color="#fffde48b" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.138461538461538" Color="#fffde388" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.430769230769231" Color="#fffde388" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.461538461538462" Color="#fffce388" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.492307692307692" Color="#fffce388" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.523076923076923" Color="#fffce287" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.538461538461538" Color="#fffce387" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.569230769230769" Color="#fffce287" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.661538829230806" Color="#fffce287" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.692307692307692" Color="#fffce286" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.846153846153846" Color="#fffce286" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.861538461538461" Color="#fffce389" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.876923076923077" Color="#fffce691" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.892307692307692" Color="#fffce89b" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.923076923076923" Color="#fffceeb3" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.953846521538498" Color="#fffcf5d1" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.969231136923114" Color="#fffcf8de" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.984615752307729" Color="#fffdfcf2" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#fff5d74a" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

If gradient is too complex you can change precision to get more approximate color and less gradient stops